Tree traversal with longest path and multiple branches in realistic timeframe
I need to determine the level or depth on longest path for each node in a tree in SQL, however I have so many variations of paths from the various branches that I cannot traverse the whole tree in under 5 minutes, even though I only have 159 nodes. Any recommendations on how to traverse the tree in a realistic timeframe?
My traversal code is below
DECLARE @treeToTraverse TABLE (
     nodeId INT
     ,NextNodeId INT
     ,UNIQUE (
         nodeId
         ,NextNodeId
         ) -- enforce unique consitraint
     )

/*
apply distinct here otherwise the joins explode the dataset making it
untraversable, behaving similarly to circular references (infinite, or near
enough in this case)
*/

INSERT INTO @treeToTraverse (
    nodeId
    ,NextNodeId
    )
SELECT DISTINCT a.nodeId
    ,a.NextNodeId
FROM a AS a
INNER JOIN q AS q ON q.Id = a.nodeId

WITH treeCte (
    nodeId
    ,NextNodeId
    ,depth
    ,pathTaken
    )
AS (
    SELECT a.nodeId
        ,a.NextNodeId
        ,1
        ,'|' + convert(VARCHAR(max), a.nodeId) + '|'
    FROM @treeToTraverse AS a
    WHERE a.nodeId = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT a.nodeId
        ,a.NextNodeId
        ,qtc.depth + 1
        ,qtc.pathTaken + convert(VARCHAR(10), a.nodeId) + '|'
    FROM @treeToTraverse AS a
    INNER JOIN treeCte AS qtc ON qtc.NextNodeId = a.nodeId
    WHERE qtc.pathTaken NOT LIKE '%|' + convert(VARCHAR(10), a.nodeId) + '|%'
    )
SELECT *
INTO #r
FROM treeCte AS qtc
ORDER BY nodeId
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)

select nodeId, max(depth) from #r 
group by nodeId


Please add some test data and expected results (no need to do all 159 nodes). Also, please specify your sql server version

Do not use a CTE. And if you can't write the SQL without a CTE, then don't do this in SQL. SQL is not optimized for graph traversal.

What is table q in INNER JOIN q AS q ON q.Id = a.nodeId ?

The other classical way to detect cycle in graph traversal when db dialect doesn't support the CYCLE instruction and if number of nodes is not too big is to use bit map, each node being represented by a 1 bit, integer math should be faster than string concatenation.

You can use some kind of "Dijkstra’s algorithm" method. For example, reduce recursive query output after several number of recursion steps by selecting max path for every node (one path for one node), and then repeat (continue) recursion.

Crawling in reverse order (starting with leaves... if you don't have leaves will mean your graph contains only cycles and the longest path will be the biggest cycle cardinality) with a breadth first algorithm should also perform better. (On a random graph of 159 nodes and about 300 edges, in depth first also I already got >6M rows at level 28... while at level 21 only 170K...)

Found a way to traverse only 1 path, instead of a traversing of all possible paths. It does however use a while loop, which does suggest that this probably shouldn't be done in SQL, as @TT suggested.
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('spr_traverseTree', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC dbo.spr_traverseTree
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.spr_traverseTree (
    @treeIdToTraverse INT
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currentNodeId INT = - 1;
    DECLARE @defaultDepthValue INT = - 1;

    SELECT @currentNodeId = q.FirstNodeID
    FROM dbo.tree AS q
    WHERE q.Id = @treeIdToTraverse

    UPDATE q
    SET q.[depth] = @defaultDepthValue
    FROM dbo.treeNodes AS q
    WHERE q.treeId = @treeIdToTraverse

    -- while the current node's depth is -1 (@defaultDepthValue), then 
    WHILE (
            SELECT iif(q.[Depth] = @defaultDepthValue, 1, 0)
            FROM dbo.treeNodes AS q
            WHERE q.id = @currentNodeId
            ) = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Current treeNodeId: ' + convert(VARCHAR(20), @currentNodeId);

        -- find if there are any other treeNodes in the tree that havent yet been traversed
        IF (@currentNodeId IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            -- in case there are multiple exists in the tree, and the current treeNode doesnt have a nexttreeNodeId but we havent explored all the paths
            SELECT TOP 1 @currentNodeId = q.Id
            FROM dbo.treeNodes AS q
            WHERE q.treeId = @treeIdToTraverse
                AND q.[Depth] = @defaultDepthValue

            -- if its still null then we have completed traverseing
            IF @currentNodeId IS NULL
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Ending traverse on treeNodeId: ' + convert(VARCHAR(20), @currentNodeId);

                BREAK;-- while
            END
        END

        DROP TABLE
        IF EXISTS #previousTreeNode;
         
        -- get all previous treeNode Depthes
        SELECT previousTreeNode.Id AS treeNodeId
            ,previousTreeNode.[Depth]
            ,previousTreeNode.ReferenceNumber
        INTO #previousTreeNode
        FROM dbo.treeNodes AS q
        INNER JOIN dbo.treeNodes AS previousTreeNode ON previousTreeNode.NextTreeNodeId = q.treeNode_Id
        WHERE q.Id = @currentNodeId

        -- if there exists a previous treeNode that has an unprocessed Depth, then move backwards
        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #previousTreeNode
                WHERE #previousTreeNode.[Depth] = @defaultDepthValue
                )
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 @currentNodeId = q.treeNodeId
            FROM #previousTreeNode AS q
            WHERE q.[Depth] = @defaultDepthValue
            ORDER BY q.treeNodeId ASC

            -- start over
            PRINT 'Set current treeNode to an unprocessed one from another branch from else where in the tree';

            CONTINUE;
        END

        DECLARE @DepthValueToUse INT;

        SELECT @DepthValueToUse = max(t.[Depth]) + 1
        FROM #previousTreeNode AS t

        IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #previousTreeNode
                )
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'No previous treeNodes found for treeNodeId: ' + convert(VARCHAR(255), @currentNodeId)

            SET @DepthValueToUse = 1
        END

        UPDATE q
        SET q.[Depth] = @DepthValueToUse
        FROM dbo.treeNodes AS q
        WHERE q.Id = @currentNodeId

        SELECT @currentNodeId = a.NexttreeNode_Id
        FROM dbo.Answer AS a
        WHERE a.treeNode_Id = @currentNodeId
    END -- while

END -- sproc

